# Unable to launch 'zoom'-meeting app on ubuntu 16.04.7

Tags: 16.04, zoom-meeting

I am trying to use the `zoom` videoconferencing application on ubuntu 16.04.7, but it does not seem to work.

I installed the probably latest version of zoom using the command

```
sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb
```

which might have installed the version 5.3.465578.0920. At the end of the install process I got the message on the terminal

```
N: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/home/alex/Downloads/zoom_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

Not the slightest idea what it means, and if this is maybe the cause of the problem.

However, I am able to 'start' zoom by typing

```
zoom
```

This opens a window:

[image]

I click on "Sign In" then choose "Sign In with SSO", and here I choose the company domain and click on "Continue".

This opens a web-page which looks like follows:

[image]

Here I click on "Open xdg-open" and briefly an icon appears on the screen

[image]

which vanishes after about 5 seconds.

If I then click on "Launch zoom" the same pop-up appears, with no change. I uninstalled and reinstalled zoom.

Is there a way to fix this? Or does zoom just not work on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there was another instance of zoom (?) running.

To fix this problem you can do

```
ps -ef | grep zoom
```

and kill every instance you find. Then restart the zoom application!

Answer (score -1):

Check your dependencies. From the [official Zoom support page](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/204206269-Installing-or-updating-Zoom-on-Linux):

> If the dependencies are not installed when using the terminal or
> graphical installer, run this command to update the package database,
> then try installing Zoom again.
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> ```
>
> If you have issues installing, make sure you have the following
> dependencies installed:
>
> ```
> libglib2.0-0
> libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 
> libxcb-shape0
> libxcb-shm0
> libxcb-xfixes0
> libxcb-randr0
> libxcb-image0
> libfontconfig1
> libgl1-mesa-glx
> libxi6
> libsm6
> libxrender1
> libpulse0
> libxcomposite1
> libxslt1.1
> libsqlite3-0
> libxcb-keysyms1
> libxcb-xtest0
> ```